# Ender 5 Spool Holder

Tags: creality-ender-5

I switched my Ender 5 to a direct drive extruder and it works great but I need a better place to put the filament spools; probably something elevated (or even just higher than the stock spool holder) that will create an easy path for the filament to go to the extruder. I've tried to find some spool holders on Thingiverse but most of them require a shelf above the printer which I do not have. Do you have any suggestions for how to fix this?

Comment: That shouldn't be that difficult as it is a 2020 Aluminium profile printer, so there must be enough ways to connect a spool holder to the frame? Maybe it is better to add an image of your setup, e.g. we don't know where there is space. If space on the sides, you could look into something like the VORON - Vertical 2020 Spool Holder, if not you need to think of a way to lay down the spool under the printer, there are examples found of that also!

Comment: I can't get a decent picture without it being over the data limit but I do have space above and to the right of the printer.

Comment: There are multiple apps (android, iOS, Windows, Linux) and applications to make an image smaller. I use e.g. GIMP. or a phone app.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a shelf - your printer is built out of 2020 aluminum extrusion so you can mount stuff directly to it easily.

Something like this will work: https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3840176
Or this one, that has like a dozen different options for attaching it to something: https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3020026

You'll need a couple of bolts and drop in T nuts to fasten it.

Comment: I just checked out those spool holders and found one that should work. I'll probably print a few and post their functionality here before closing the question to recommend which version worked best. Thanks for your help!